# RetryError[<Future at 0x23f38d59150 state=finished raised APIRemovedInV1>]

Tags: python, telegram, openai-api, chatgpt-api

Trying to connect to an OpenAI api after a few months, but a RetryError[<Future at 0x23f38d59150 state=finished raised APIRemovedInV1>] error occurs. I have already searched many sites and tried many ways to solve the problem, but it is not solved. Api key is working.I'm trying to connect to a bot on Telegram.
Here is the code for connecting to the api:

```
import openai 
from keys import open_ai_key 


from tenacity import (
    retry,
    stop_after_attempt,
    wait_random_exponential,
) 

openai.api_key = open_ai_key # OpenAi


@retry(wait=wait_random_exponential(min=1, max=3), stop=stop_after_attempt(6))
def open_ai(text):
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo-1106", 
        messages=[{"role": "user", "content": f"{text}"}])
    
    v = (response['choices'][0]['message'])

    return v['content']
```